# Should you clone Date object before get in Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've heard that it's a problem that `Date` is not thread safe, but haven't found any practical explanation when this might end bad. I know when parsing with `DateFormat` ends badly, but `Date`?

So as an example would using Date as below end up in something nasty for multi-threaded environment?

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Throwable.class})
public void moveToArchive(UserContext userContext, long id) throws PostFailedException {
        PostEntity postEntity;
        try {
            postEntity = postDAO.get(userContext.getUserId(), id);
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new PostFailedException(PostFailedException.ITEM_NOT_FOUND, ex);
        }
        //...
        // copying java.util.Date between entities
        archivedPostEntity.setCreationDate(post.getCreationDate());
        //...
}
```

So is it bad if `getCreationDate` just returns internal property? Or will Spring/Hibernate handle this correctly?

What should `getCreationDate` look like?

Something like this is fine?

```
@Entity
public class PostEntity implements Post {
//...
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date postDate;
//... 
    @Override
    public Date getPostDate() {
        return postDate;
    }
}
```

Or maybe it should be more like this?

```
@Entity
public class PostEntity implements Post {
//...
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date postDate;
//... 
    @Override
    public synchronized Date getPostDate() {
        return new Date(postDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is using modern (Java 8) APIs possible?

Comment: The troublesome `Date` and `DateFormat` are now legacy, outmoded years ago, supplanted entirely by the java.time classes. Specifically: `Instant`, `OffsetDateTine`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Date object is not thread-safe. Your approach of creating a new Date via the getPostDate() method will work to circumvent this issue for the most part. In fact it is considered best practice.

Now regardless of thread safety it is recommended that you recreate (clone or whatever) the Date object when returned from an entity. FindBugs will actually look for this issue in your POJO's. The reason is that Date is mutable unlike the String class for example.

Thus returning the live reference from an Entity bean allows the Date object within the Entity to be mutated without the use of the corresponding set method in the Entity. The entity will have no idea if its internal state has changed and if it needs to be persisted to the data store. This sort of defect occurs more often than you would like to admit.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

> I've heard that it's a problem that `Date` is not thread safe, but
>   haven't found any practical explanation when this might end bad.

Perhaps you are focusing your search too narrowly.  `Date` not being thread-safe presents the same problems, in the same contexts, as any other mutable class not being thread-safe does, and it affords the same solutions.

> I
>   know when parsing with `DateFormat` ends badly, but `Date`?

`Date` instances are mutable.  If one is shared between threads, and it is mutated without proper external synchronization, then the behavior of the program is not well-defined.

> So as an example would using Date as below end up in something nasty
>   for multi-threaded environment? [...]

It could do, if, again, that allows the same `Date` instance to be accessed by different threads, and if at least one of those threads modifies that instance after its instantiation.  Different threads might then get inconsistent views of the `Date`'s value, and that could ripple through the application, causing other inconsistencies.

> So is it bad if getCreationDate just returns internal property? Or
>   will Spring/Hibernate handle this correctly?

Spring and Hibernate will not automagically provide thread safety in this area.  In fact, they may well facilitate your entities, and thus the values of their properties, being shared between threads.  To that extent, they are part of the problem.  Hibernate itself is thread safe, but that is not sufficient.

> What should getCreationDate look like? [...]

You are asking whether to employ defensive copying in your entity implementations, and in your property getters in particular.  Defensive copying primarily protects you from having the internal state of your entity modified without use of the entity's own methods.  In this particular case, it will also minimize -- but not eliminate -- your `Date` instances being shared between threads.  These provide some protection, but they are in no way a complete solution.

To fully eliminate problems arising from your entities having fields of type `Date`, you need to perform defensive copying in getters and setters both, and you must furthermore *synchronize* those defensive copying operations.  But you do not need to synchronize on the whole entity, and avoiding that may improve performance if you have multiple properties in need of such treatment.  For instance,

```
@Entity
public class PostEntity implements Post {
//...
    @NotNull
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date postDate = new Date();
    private final Object postDateMonitor = new Object();
//... 

    @Override
    public Date getPostDate() {
        synchronized (postDateMonitor) {
            return new Date(postDate.getTime());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setPostDate(Date date) {
        synchronized (postDateMonitor) {
            postDate = new Date(date.getTime());
        }
    }
}
```